# Adding a check to account creation script

Tags: shell

I've inherited the following script to create accounts in OSX.

I'd like to include a check into it that first checks to see if an account already exists on the destination with that name, and if so, echoes a message "Account Exists", then takes no other action and then moves on.

A typical /tmp/list.txt consists of just shortnames, I.e.:

```
jdoe
brianx
peterm
smithd
```

Your help is much appreciated!

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
        echo mkhdir: Did not find required argument: group name
        echo Usage: mkhdir \[group\]
        exit 1
fi

for i in  `cat /tmp/list.txt` ; do
if [ ! -r /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i ]
   then
      mkdir /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
      mkdir /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i/Backups
fi
chown -R $i:$1 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
chmod -R 700 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
find /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i -type d -exec chmod 701 {} \;
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test for `[ ! -r ... ]` won't tell if you /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i is a directory or not. Use

```
for i in  `cat /tmp/list.txt` ; do
    if [ ! -d /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i ] ; then
         mkdir /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
    else 
       echo "/Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i already exists" >&2
    fi
    if [ ! -d /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i/Backups ] ; then
        mkdir /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i/Backups
    else
        echo "/Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i/Backups already exists" >&2
    fi
    chown -R $i:$1 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
    chmod -R 700 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
    find /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i -type d -exec chmod 701 {} \;
done
```

`701` Anyone know what the purpose is for `701` in the final `find ... chmod`?

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

@shellter  thanks! I've added a closing quotation mark to the echo line and it works perfectly!

Finished script snippet:

```
for i in  `cat /tmp/list.txt` ; do
    if [ ! -d /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i ] ; then
         mkdir /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
    else 
       echo "/Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i already exists" >&2
    fi
    if [ ! -d /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i/Backups ] ; then
        mkdir /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i/Backups
    else
        echo "/Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i/Backups already exists" >&2
    fi
    chown -R $i:$1 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
    chmod -R 700 /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i
    find /Volumes/UserStorage/Users/$i -type d -exec chmod 701 {} \;
done
```

Comment: tnx, got it. The `>&2` sends error msgs to std-err, which is "the standard" :-). Good luck.